# Ftp Upload and File Reading

Tags: c++, file, file-upload

My program is working ,but it retains the old command value of x and the old ID value of y and continues to execute 'command 1'. I'm trying to get the program to proceed to check for another 'commands.txt',stores the x/y, compare the values ,and finally loop all over again. For some reason it is keeping the values once I feed the program them by uploading a commands.txt file. I can't get it to stop doing that.

Here is my code. Bare in mind, I'm quite new to C++.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <lmcons.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")

using namespace std;

int startup(string IDpath){

    ifstream file;
    file.open(IDpath);
    bool TF = file.is_open();

    if (TF == FALSE){ // checks if the ID file exists
        int RN;       // creates a random ID 
        srand(time(0));
        RN = rand() % 1000;

        ofstream create; // stores ID in a file
        create.open(IDpath);
        create << RN << endl;
        create.close();
    }

    int x;       // passes ID to main         
    ifstream wID;
    wID.open(IDpath);
    wID >> x;
    wID.close();
    return x;

}

int check (int w, int z, int cID){

    if (w = 1 && z == cID){
        cout << "command 1 executed!" << w << z <<endl;
        return 0;


    }
    else
        return 0;


}

int main(){

    int x;
    int y;
    int ID;

    TCHAR username[UNLEN + 1]; // gets username
    DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
    GetUserName((TCHAR*)username, &size);
    string name = username; // stores username

    string path = "C://Users//"; // creates universal path for ID
    string path2 = "//Downloads//ID.txt";
    string finalpathID = path + name + path2;

    string pathRC = "C://Users//"; // creates universal path for reading the commands
    string path2RC = "//Downloads//readcommands.txt";
    string finalpathRC = pathRC + name + path2RC;
    LPCSTR FPRC = finalpathRC.c_str();

    startup(finalpathID); // passes the ID path
    ID = startup(finalpathID); // stores ID value in 'ID'

    while (true){


        HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0); // internet handle
        HINTERNET hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "ftp.YOURHOST.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "PASSWORD", "USERNAME", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0); // ftp handle
        FtpSetCurrentDirectory(hFtpSession, "htdocs"); // sets ftp directory


        FtpGetFile(hFtpSession, "commands.txt", FPRC, FALSE, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
        FtpDeleteFile(hFtpSession, "commands.txt");

        ifstream file;
        file.open(finalpathRC);
        file >> x >> y; // takes in the command and ID value
        file.close();

        InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession); // closes ftp handle
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet); // closes internet handle 

        if (check(x, y, ID) == 0){

            remove(FPRC);
            continue;


        }


    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The program appears to download commands.txt and then attempt to delete it. It doesn't check the return code for either the download or the delete, so you can't be sure it has accomplished either. The file IO is also unchecked, so there are no assurances that the file has been successfully read.

The program may have downloaded and failed to delete and thus keep downloading and processing the same file.

Or it may have deleted the file and subsequent downloads are failing unchecked. The program fails to open the file, fails to read x and y and appears to be reading the same file.

Solution: Check the error codes and modify program behaviour accordingly.